# Why can't I print to console after try block in Java?

Tags: java, android, try-catch

I have the following code in an Android application:

```
public static HttpResponse dbPost(String handlerUrl, List<NameValuePair> postData) {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String postUrl = constants.postUrl(); 
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(postUrl);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    System.out.print("Catch 0");

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postData));
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.print("Catch 1");

    return response;

}
```

I have a button that calls this block.  If I press the button, the console will print "Catch 0" (but NOT "Catch 1").  If I press the button again (same instance), the console will print "Catch1Catch0".  What's the problem?

I'm a bit new to Java so bear with me.

Comment: Is an error being caught and the stack trace printing?  Maybe your missing it after the stack trace?

Comment: is any exception being thrown?

Comment: No errors.  Tried the println listed below and that was my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call [flush](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#flush%28%29) since you're using `print`.

```
System.out.print("Catch 1");
System.out.flush();
```

The default behavior of `PrintStream` is to only flush when a newline is written.  (This behavior is documented in [write(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#write%28int%29).)

If you used `printLn` instead of `print`, the stream would flush automatically.  Without that, you need to explicitly flush the output stream.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `print` rather than `println`.

Comment: so what? Should give more information other than writing exact solution.